# Algorithm for random numbers

Tags: random, numbers

I have to implement an algorithm for a raffle. The problem is that i would like that some of the participant to have more chances, because they have more points. How can i do that?
I thounght to simply put them many times in the raffle, but doesn't seems legit.
Do you know any algorithms that can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Give them more "tickets", just like one does at a raffle where tickets are given away at the door .. but each ticket has the same odds being chosen. (For each ticket given away at a door, another matching ticket stub is added to the pile that can be chosen from.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't that be "legit". If you base your amount of chance on a number of points, you add the person for X times in the raffle based on his points. That person's chance increase.

I would solve it in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo algorithm:

```
winnerTicket <- a random number between zero and sum ticket count - 1
currentTicket <- 0
For each participant in participants ordered by id
    If winnerTicket - currentTicket > participant.ticketCount
        currentTicket += participant.ticketCount
    Else
        return participant
```

Comment: Does the order and sorting of participants matter here?

Answer (score 1):

You have a mapping: `participant => number of chances`. In many programming languages you can declare a mapping or dictionary like this:

```
{"player1": 2, "player2": 5, ... many more like these}
```

so you can iterate like this:

```
accumulatedMap = {} #an empty map
total = 0
for each pair of key:count in the mapping:
    total = total + count
    accumulatedMap[key] = total

#now, get random and calculate
element = random between 1 and total, inclusive.
for each pair of key:accumulated in the mapping:
    if element <= accumulated:
        return key
#at this point, in the worst case the last key was returned.
```

This code is just an example. Remember that mappings don't always keep an insertion order when iterating.